# Lying in video games haram? (Among Us)

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, game, lying

There is a game that you need to be in a team and one of them is imposter. And whoever is imposter, he need to hide his and identity and lie about certain things. Everyone in the game knows someone is lying and they know that this game requires to lie.

So will the person in video game who has to lie get sin for that? **Even though everyone in game agreed to that.** From example popular game "[Among Us](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innersloth.spacemafia)"

Comment: Video games are haram, so anything that follows that, it'll also be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عُثْمَانَ الدِّمَشْقِيُّ أَبُو الْجُمَاهِرِ ، قَالَ : حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو كَعْبٍ أَيُّوبُ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ السَّعْدِيُّ ، قَالَ : حَدَّثَنِي سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ حَبِيبٍ الْمُحَارِبِيُّ ، عَنْ أَبِي أُمَامَةَ قَالَ : قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " أَنَا زَعِيمٌ بِبَيْتٍ فِي رَبَضِ الْجَنَّةِ لِمَنْ تَرَكَ الْمِرَاءَ وَإِنْ كَانَ مُحِقًّا، وَبِبَيْتٍ فِي وَسَطِ الْجَنَّةِ لِمَنْ تَرَكَ الْكَذِبَ وَإِنْ كَانَ مَازِحًا، وَبِبَيْتٍ فِي أَعْلَى الْجَنَّةِ لِمَنْ حَسُنَ خُلُقُهُ ".

Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "I guarantee a house in Jannah for one who gives up arguing, even if he is in the right; and I guarantee a home in the middle of Jannah for one who abandons lying even for the sake of fun; and I guarantee a house in the highest part of Jannah for one who has good manners."

Abandon lying even if joking !

Also in another hadeeth :

Adhere (you people) to truth, for truth leads to good deeds and good deeds lead to Paradise, and if a man continues to speak the truth and makes truth his object he will be recorded as truthful before Allah. Avoid (you people) falsehood, for falsehood leads to wickedness and wickedness leads to Hell, and if a man continues to speak falsehood and makes falsehood his object he will be recorded as a liar before Allah.” Agreed upon.

عَنِ اِبْنِ مَسْعُودٍ ‏- رضى الله عنه ‏- قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اَللَّهِ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-{ عَلَيْكُمْ بِالصِّدْقِ, فَإِنَّ اَلصِّدْقَ يَهْدِي إِلَى اَلْبِرِّ, وَإِنَّ اَلْبِرَّ يَهْدِي إِلَى اَلْجَنَّةِ, وَمَا يَزَالُ اَلرَّجُلُ يَصْدُقُ, وَيَتَحَرَّى اَلصِّدْقَ, حَتَّى يُكْتَبَ عِنْدَ اَللَّهِ صِدِّيقًا, وَإِيَّاكُمْ وَالْكَذِبَ, فَإِنَّ اَلْكَذِبَ يَهْدِي إِلَى اَلْفُجُورِ, وَإِنَّ اَلْفُجُورَ يَهْدِي إِلَى اَلنَّارِ, وَمَا يَزَالُ اَلرَّجُلُ يَكْذِبُ, وَيَتَحَرَّى اَلْكَذِبَ, حَتَّى يُكْتَبَ عِنْدَ اَللَّهِ كَذَّابًا } مُتَّفَقٌ عَلَيْهِ .‏ 1‏ .‏

Lying even in a game will seed in someone heart a bad plant when keep lying even in joking at the end it will be a habit!

I watched some YouTubers play that game you need to lie!

Answer (score 3):

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I also want you to consider you been asking about want you spent time doing, Because verily the massager of Allah said, "The feet of a servant will not move on the Day of Judgment until he is questioned about his life: how he spent it…” [At-Tirmithi].

Not even talking of lying in game, please my brother let stay away from it, Allah Azawajal will guide us

And Allah knows all, wasalamu alaikum

Comment: whoa. really strict isn't

Answer (score -2):

I think among us is haram beacause in the among us game you need to lie and when you get imposter role you have to kill in the game and lying is haram killing is haram.