# Is among us haram?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

There's this game I used to play with my friend called "Among Us". In this game you are given a role of "crewmate" or "imposter". In this game if your an imposter you have to lie and try to win and the crewmates have to find out who the imposter is. Since this is a game, everyone knows that you are lying. I heard people say that this is haram (that's why I stopped playing it) but me  and my friend would get in a call and we would talk, I tought my friend while playing this game stuff about Islam and we teach and talk to each other about stuff including about Islam. I also pray on time and dont delay or miss my prayers so is it haram?

Comment: dont play Among Us, problem solved

Comment: StackExchange owner is not a Muslim @Rafid. he might buy something haram from ads revenue. that might be a problem for you as well. not me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lying in video games haram? (Among Us)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62489/lying-in-video-games-haram-among-us)

Comment: @abdullahsaid the issue is about the content, not the ownership. if we use your logic, then everything is a problem, even when buying a Mushaf, or a book of a hadith.

Comment: don't use logic, problem solved, stay that way. don't change @Rafid

Answer (score -1):

Sins such as lying are even allowed in some urgent circumstances. for example, to keep solidarity intact or being a captive at war. but lying in games is a bit controversial, it is allowed when you have a good intention, and your friend also aware that you're lying. same as for board games like chess, even that we didn't say a word but we tricked our opponent to fell into our strategy trap. so IMO this is totally fine